# Converting formal class rasterlayer to spatialgriddataframe

Tags: r, raster, spatial-data-frame

hopefully someone can help me.

I've got some slope data in the form of a formal class `RasterLayer`and by using the command `as(slope, 'spatialGridDataFrame')`, I've managed to convert it to a large `spatialgriddataframe`. However when I look at the data frame my variable, the slope angle, is filled with `NA` values. Though I don't understand as when I plot the grid it displays the slope angles see image. [image: slope, plotted] **How do I make the variable in my spatialgriddata frame represent the slope angles?**

#### This is the formalraster information  [image: formalraster info.1]

[image: formalraster info.2]

#### This image is the spatialGridDataFrame infomation

[image: spatialGridDataFrame info]
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the pictures as part of your question rather than providing links to them.

Comment: Is it possible that only the first values are `NA`? Could you add the output of `summary(yourSGDF)` to the question, please?

Comment: surprised you were able to convert it. When I try the same I get "no method or default for coercing “RasterLayer” to “spatialGridDataFrame”"

Comment: edit: this does work but needs uppercase S in SpatialGridDataFrame - see same formatting in OPs question.